# Can't set up image in the div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a div, which contains:

- Text on the top
- Some image below it

How I may make it? Here's what I did so far

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180pt;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  width: 12%;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("url_to_img");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For now, the `<p>` is working just fine, but I have struggle with the image it's  sticking out the borders of container div.

Comment: A **background** image cannot exceed the size of it's parent. Please  demonstrate the problem.

Comment: read about positioning, absolute and reltive

Answer (score 0):

It's because you gave the  `test` class too much margin. try not to mix up size units if possible.

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow:hidden;` on **.text** class

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180pt;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  width: 19%;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1380368/3e559dd1-32ad-4226-aac5-77ed3782a962/s1200");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle to get you started with, I didn't change much code because I didn't new your requirements Just did workaround around same code

https://jsfiddle.net/junaidmasoodi/vctwu2g5/11/

```
.text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("https://309w5s255371fs4df2vftgbl-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for your `.image` block you could try  `background-size: contain;` instead of `cover`